Polars truncates decimals
I'm trying to truncate floating point numbers in my DataFrame to a desired number of decimal places. I've found that this can be done using Pandas and NumPy here, but I've also seen that it might be possible with polars.Config.set_float_precision.
Below is my current approach, but I think I might be taking extra steps.
import polars as pl

data = {
    "name": ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"],
    "grade": [90.23456, 80.98765, 85.12345],
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)

(
    df
    # Convert to string
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("grade").map_elements(
            lambda x: f"{x:.5f}", 
            return_dtype=pl.String
        ).alias("formatted_grade")
    )
    # Slice to get desired decimals
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("formatted_grade").str.slice(0, length = 4)
    )
    # Convert back to Float
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("formatted_grade").cast(pl.Float64)
    )
)


https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/misc/styling/#format-limit-decimal-places

@MichaelCao Hi, this way its rounding decimals, i need to truncate it. Also, i need to keep doing other operations on the dataframe

Since you mentioned polars.Config.set_float_precision: This is a config setting which controls only how float values are displayed in a dataframe. The underlying values stay untouched.

You can use the Polars - Numpy integration like this:
df = df.with_columns(truncated_grade=np.trunc(pl.col("grade") * 10) / 10)

Output:
┌─────────┬──────────┬─────────────────┐
│ name    ┆ grade    ┆ truncated_grade │
│ ---     ┆ ---      ┆ ---             │
│ str     ┆ f64      ┆ f64             │
╞═════════╪══════════╪═════════════════╡
│ Alice   ┆ 90.23456 ┆ 90.2            │
│ Bob     ┆ 80.98765 ┆ 80.9            │
│ Charlie ┆ 85.12345 ┆ 85.1            │
└─────────┴──────────┴─────────────────┘

Full code:
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

data = {
    "name": ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"],
    "grade": [90.23456, 80.98765, 85.12345],
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)
df = df.with_columns(truncated_grade=np.trunc(pl.col("grade") * 10) / 10)

print(df)


use round:
import polars as pl

data = {
"name": ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"],
"grade": [90.23456, 80.98765, 85.12345],

}
df = pl.DataFrame(data).with_columns( pl.col("grade").cast(pl.Utf8).str.extract(r'^(\d+.\d{2})').cast(pl.Float64).alias("formatted_grade") )

OP mentioned that they doesn't want to round the decimal numbers, but truncate them.

Ok. We can cast it to string and extract it upto the needed decimal value and later again cast that to float : pl.DataFrame(data).with_columns(
pl.col("grade").cast(pl.Utf8).str.extract(r'^(\d+.\d{2})').cast(pl.Float64).alias("formatted_grade")
)
